# Problem with getting e.target value from an asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I've got a little problem with getting value from an asynchronous function and then use it in the e.target function. I want to be able to click one of two lists (names and surnames) and then show in the div called 'result' the result. I read lots of articles but none of them was straight accurate to my problem :( What am I doing wrong?

```js
async function getData() {
    let url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cuSKqtKmgi?indent=2';
    try {
        let res = await fetch(url);
        return await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function renderUsers() {
    const nameList = document.querySelector('.name-list')
    const surnameList = document.querySelector('.surname-list')
    let data = await getData();
    let names = '';
    let surnames = '';
    data.person.forEach(user => {
        let htmlSegment = `
                            <li>${user.name}</li>
                            `;

        names += htmlSegment;
    });
    data.person.forEach(user => {
        let htmlSegment = `
                            <li>${user.surrname}</li>
                            `;

        surnames += htmlSegment;
    });
    nameList.innerHTML = names;
    surnameList.innerHTML = surnames;
}
const chooseUser = (e) => {
    const result = document.querySelector('.result')
    const origin = e.target;
    result.textContent = origin.textContent;

}
const showUser = () => {
    const menu = document.querySelectorAll('ul li')
    menu.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener('click', chooseUser)
    });
}
renderUsers();
showUser()
```

```css
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
ul li{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
 <nav>
        <ul class="name-list">
        </ul>
        <ul class="surname-list">
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="result"></div>
```

If something is unclear feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of things I would fix in this program -

- Keep functions synchronous wherever possible
- Functions should take arguments and return results
- Write generic functions that can be reused
- Using `.innerHTML` to build complex documents forces all of your data through the String interface
- Error handling should not be part of your fetching function. Let the caller decide what to do

```js
const getJSON = url =>                             // <- generic
  fetch(url).then(r => r.json())

function li(text)
{ const e = document.createElement("li")           // <- use DOM api
  e.textContent = text
  return e                                         // <- returns value
}

function appendUsers(elem, users)
{ const names = elem.querySelector(".name-list")
  const surnames = elem.querySelector(".surname-list")
  for (const u of users)
  { names.appendChild(li(u.name))                  // <- DOM api
    surnames.appendChild(li(u.surrname))
  }
}

const showUser = (elem, name) =>
  elem.textContent = name

async function main(url)
{ const nav = document.querySelector("nav")        // <- once
  const result = document.querySelector("#result") // <- once
  const data = await getJSON(url)                  // <- generic
  appendUsers(nav, data.person)                    // <- synchronous
  nav.addEventListener("click", e => {
    showUser(result, e.target.textContent)
  })
}

main("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cuSKqtKmgi?indent=2")
  .catch(console.error)                            // <- err handler
```

```css
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
ul li{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="name-list">
    </ul>
    <ul class="surname-list">
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, your response is really impressive. To be honest, I'm starting my long journey with coding, that's why my code quality is not as good as yours. Thank you for all the tips, I'll try to improve that in the future :)

Comment: @Stairss You're very welcome :D We all start somewhere. My hope is to help you avoid making things harder than they have to be. If you have any questions, I'm happy to assist.

Answer (score 2):

```
renderUsers().then(r=>{
    showUser()
})
```

**Why ?:**
`renderUsers` is async function

so, without `then( ... )`, `showUser()` will called before render items.
so, `const menu = document.querySelectorAll('ul li')` will return empty list

Comment: Thank you sir, this is exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

Well the `renderUsers` is async, so at the time you call `showUser` there are no `li` elements to be selected. You could call `showUser` at the end of `renderUsers` or just create async block and await for `renderUsers` to resolve first.

```js
async function getData() {
  let url = 'https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cuSKqtKmgi?indent=2';
  try {
    let res = await fetch(url);
    return await res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

async function renderUsers() {
  const nameList = document.querySelector('.name-list')
  const surnameList = document.querySelector('.surname-list')
  let data = await getData();
  let names = '';
  let surnames = '';
  data.person.forEach(user => {
    let htmlSegment = `<li>${user.name}</li>`;
    names += htmlSegment;
  });
  data.person.forEach(user => {
    let htmlSegment = ` <li>${user.surrname}</li>`;
    surnames += htmlSegment;
  });
  nameList.innerHTML = names;
  surnameList.innerHTML = surnames;
}

const chooseUser = (e) => {
  const result = document.querySelector('.result')
  const origin = e.target;
  result.textContent = origin.textContent;

}

const showUser = () => {
  const menu = document.querySelectorAll('ul li')
  menu.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', chooseUser));
}

(async() => {
  await renderUsers();
  showUser()
})()
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="name-list">
  </ul>
  <ul class="surname-list">
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="result"></div>
```